# DataTable in GridView with scientific notation (ASP .NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, matlab, gridview, datatable

I have a problem, that I was hoping you could help me solve.

I have this DataTable that I want displayed in a GridView. That itself is not a problem. The problem is that I would very much like it displayed with scientific notation. It is also using "," as decimal seperator, which I would like to be "." instead.

In short: I would like to go from "xxxxxx,xxxxxx" to something like "xx.xxexxx".

The DataTable contains 9 values. It's a 3x3 matrix I have received after calling a Matlab function (output type MWNumericArray). I'm not even sure converting it to DataTable was the right choice in the first place.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: BTW I'm very new to C#!

Comment: I've tried adding  "DataFormatString="{0:e}"" in asp:GridView. That's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't change formatting in the datatable, that happens on the datagridview itself.

But it's quite simple to do from Visual Studios.

1. Right click the datagridview and select edit columns
2. Go to Appearance -> DefaultCellStyle
3. Then under CellStyle builder, under Behavior click edit on Format
4. Select scientific

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, my problem isn't solved yet. Which version of VS do you use? Mine looks slightly different:
![Pic](http://i.imgur.com/5aMsIIx.png).

Comment: This is from VS2012. The process should be similar for the version you are working with.